# a windows service monitors local system time to start other services?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

need your advices on this scenario:
I have a bunch of services installed on a server, they need to be set to start and stop dynamically depending on the local system time, meaning the start time and end time are different almost everyday, e.g, today these services are set to start by 9am and end by 9pm, and tomorrow could be 10:30 am and 9pm.

starttime and endtime are stored in an xml file that is generated on daily basis

So, I'm thinking about using another service to read the xml file and triggers the services accordingly, but it needs to be real time so it always monitors the local system time.

If this is possible how exactly I should do to achieve this programatically?

Comment: Who or what generates the xml file that's used as basis for start time and end time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a script that can stop and start every service pair those with scheduled tasks.  then you can programmaticaly modify the scheduled remotely even if needed.  Creating your own service will be error prone.